Affordable food-grade high-viscosity pump
I am looking for a affordable electric-powered pump to pump high viscosity chunky mayonnaise-based dips (the chunks are things like blended olive, diced and caramelized onions, string-y scallion, etc).
If there anyone knows of one available from a Canadian supplier, that would be even better.
Thanks!

you can ask about which type of pump is suitable ... you cannot ask where to buy one

For high viscosity, the challenge is on the in-feed side. You only have 1bar of suction to work with. So generally one would use a pump with larger diameter flow path than the same flow rate with a water-like viscosity. Talking to a component salesperson who has worked with food-process customers would probably be the most practical thing to do here. In extreme situations, you might see an auger mechanism, but mayo isn't necessarily that bad, the chunks might be the more important part. Mayo might also be non-newtonian (eg shear thinning). not a deal breaker tho.

@PeteW Yes it seems it is non-newtonian. I'm thinking of designing one in CAD and getting it CNCed if it isn't too much... What diameter input do you think it should have?

Closest thing I saw myself was a hair coloring device, which dispensed a gel. This was probably overkill, but we went with an experimental-analytical approach. Using a pressure regulator and a cup/balance to measure flow, we constructed graphs of flow-vs-pressure, for various diameter tubes. Had it been water, the lines on the graph would all have gone through the (0,0) point on the graph. With this stuff, they were "hockey stick" shapes. The place where they started to rise (at various slopes, per diameter), were shifted to a certain pressure where it "released". Beyond that it was linear.

So we set up our system to avoid the sticky zone, and also avoid the transition zone, and the pumping went fine after that. This was all probably overkill, but we had the equipment to do the experiments so it wasn't too hard. I suspect trial-and-error approach, or just asking someone in the industry for folk wisdom, could have worked too. I have a feeling mayonnaise might be worse, and perhaps also more sensitive to temperature if refrigerated.

Another thing I've seen in factory setups, with gels, is to apply additional positive pressure on the in-feed side of the actual pump which determines a flow. This is more possible if the material is supplied in a syringe, or a bucket, or a cylindrical barrel. In which case a plunger (with an exit hole to which a fairly large tube hooks up) can be constructed to squeeze it out - and this can eliminate the issue with limited negative pressure. I'd seriously consider reaching out to someone with direct experience with your material. It can save you time and you might learn about other pitfalls

Your best bet is a high-capacity, variable speed programmable peristaltic pump equipped with food grade tubing. They cost several thousand dollars each unless you buy used on ebay.
